# Removing phantom table cells in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt

I apologize if this has been asked before.  I tried to do a thorough search, but I suppose could be using the wrong terms.

At any rate.  I have some data that is generated dynamically and popped into a table, all via some XSLT magic.  I also figured out a way to dynamically check if a given entry in the table needs to span two or more table cells and do that.

*Unfortunately*, running in the colspan attribute is adding table cells to the end of my table.  I had a screenshot of this, but I'm not reputable enough to post pictures.

I've investigated just about every way to deal with that in xslt and have come to the conclusion that the answer lies in javascript/jquery.

I've gotten this far:

```
var ths = $('table.calendar > tbody > tr > th');
var tds = $('table.calendar > tbody > tr > td');
thLength = ths.length;
tdLength = tds.length;

//all good so far

if(tdLength > thLength) { //which it most certainly is
    //somehow delete the unwanted element(s) in the td array, like:
    for(var i = tdLength; i > thLength; i--) {
        $(tds[i]).remove();
    }
}
```

Except that's not working.  And, granted, this is probably because I'm a hacky coder, at best.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and `remove`, but you'll want to do it *per row*; your `$('table.calendar > tbody > tr > td');` will give you cells from multiple rows in the same jQuery object.

So:

```
var ths = $('table.calendar > tbody > tr > th');
var thLength = ths.length;
$('table.calendar > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    var tds = $(this).children('td');
    tds.slice(thLength).remove();
});
```

You can, of course, combine those two lines inside the callback:

```
    $(this).children('td').slice(thLength).remove();
```

Note that that assumes you have only a single row of `th` elements. (Which should probably be in `thead` rather than `tbody`, FWIW.)

Also note that none of this takes `colspan` into account at all. If you're using `colspan`, you can't just base what you're doing on how many cells there are (since a single cell spans columns).

> **`slice`**
>
> Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices.

Takes `start` and `end`; if you leave `end` off, it goes to the end of the set.

**Live Example:**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var ths = $('table.calendar > tbody > tr > th');
  var thLength = ths.length;
  $('table.calendar > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    var tds = $(this).children('td');
    tds.slice(thLength).remove();
  });
}, 500);
```

```html
<p>Table will update after a brief delay.</p>
<table class="calendar">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
      <th>Four</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1-1</td>
      <td>1-2</td>
      <td>1-3</td>
      <td>1-4</td>
      <td>1-5</td>
      <td>1-6</td>
      <td>1-7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1-1</td>
      <td>1-2</td>
      <td>1-3</td>
      <td>1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1-1</td>
      <td>1-2</td>
      <td>1-3</td>
      <td>1-4</td>
      <td>1-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1-1</td>
      <td>1-2</td>
      <td>1-3</td>
      <td>1-4</td>
      <td>1-5</td>
      <td>1-6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome and thank you.  I'm marking this as the answer because, if I weren't a moron, this would absolutely work. The problem is, the issue is being caused by the colspan.  I guess it's not -really- a phantom cell, as the count of table cells matches the number of table headers; my colspan doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Oh, also, to your point about the ths: they _should_ be in a thead element, but SharePoint makes the choice to structure the tables that way.  Go figure.

Comment: @ChrisPEditor: Ah, well...SharePoint. 'Nuff said. :-)

Comment: Don't I know it.  My lot in life.  Thanks again. :)